# Debugging SLF4J post Gradle Conversion

Tags: gradle, log4j, slf4j

Very annoying... we converted our project to Gradle and logging does not work anymore. I selected imports that matched our current version of 1.6.6 but the only output we get is just time info like this:

> Thu Aug 14 18:51:53 EDT 2014

SLF4J is the implementation and we are using a log4j.xml file to do the setup that is stored at the classes directory. If I run unit tests from Eclipse the logging mechanism works fine, but after deploying it to Tomcat I have no luck. I tried updating to the latest version as well but that did not solve the problem.

Here's the current gradle entry:

```
compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.7'
compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:1.7.7'
```

And like I said, we're using a log4jxml.file for configuration which is rather long and may not be necessary (only because, like I said, this was working before), but here's a short version that doesn't work:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration PUBLIC "-//APACHE//DTD LOG4J 1.2//EN" "log4j.dtd">
<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">

<!-- Appenders -->
<appender name="console" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
    <param name="Target" value="System.out" />
    <param name="Threshold" value="info"/>
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%-5p: %c - %m%n LOGTEST" />
    </layout>
</appender>

    <appender name="file" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
      <param name="append" value="false"/>
      <param name="Threshold" value="info"/>
      <param name="file" value="${catalina.base}/logs/application.log"/>
      <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
         <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{ABSOLUTE} %-5p [%c{1}] %m%n"/>
      </layout>
   </appender>

    <logger name="org.springframework.ws">
        <level value="trace" />
    </logger>

    <!-- Root Logger -->
    <root>
        <priority value="trace" />
        <appender-ref ref="file" />
        <appender-ref ref="errorFile" />
        <appender-ref ref="console" />
    </root>

</log4j:configuration>
```

this does work for running Unit tests in Eclipse. But if I deploy this to Tomcat and start the server from Eclipse I don't get output anymore. Note the "LOGTEST" string above. Here's what my console log output looks like:

```
LOGTESTINFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/resources/**] onto handler 'org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler#0'
LOGTESTINFO : com.mycompany.cerp.app.MyApp - Loading trusted certs from C:\tomcat\webapps\ROOT\WEB-INF\validcerts
LOGTESTINFO : com.mycompany.cerp.app.MyApp - Loading Certificate: C:\tomcat\webapps\ROOT\WEB-INF\validcerts\certs_output.crt
LOGTESTINFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - FrameworkServlet 'mvc-dispatcher': initialization completed in 874 ms
LOGTESTAug 18, 2014 6:34:56 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8000"]
Aug 18, 2014 6:34:56 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Aug 18, 2014 6:34:56 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 8561 ms
Aug 18, 2014 6:35:06 PM org.apache.jasper.compiler.TldLocationsCache tldScanJar
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
Thu Aug 14 18:51:53 EDT 2014
Thu Aug 14 18:51:53 EDT 2014
```

Note that the last two lines reflect the custom logger disappearing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The nature of this problem and that I couldn't see the solution represents a certain willful ignorance about dependencies. If I'm using slf4j with log4j as the underlying implementation, why would I need two separate imports? In other words, by its very nature **slf4j-log4j12:1.7.7**, requires both slf4j and log4j, so these latter shouldn't need to be listed as dependencies.

The two import statements I was using in the OP were incompatible and I fixed this problem by changing the import to just:

```
compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:1.7.7'
```